# Finding the transition matrix for a hexagonal bipyramid

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I need to find the transition matrix for a hexagonal bipyramid. I believe it has something to do with the degree of the vertices. I know the degree of the top and bottom vertices are both 6, and the degree of all other vertices is 4. How do I put this together into a matrix?

This is to create a Markov chain of going from one vertex to another.

Comment: What is the transition matrix of a polyhedron? If you mean the adjacency matrix of the graph formed by its edges, just label the vertices and build the matrix using the edge-vertex incidence.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I am trying to create a Markov chain.

Comment: How does this comment makes anything clearer?

Comment: Are you talking about a [hexagonal **bi**pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_bipyramid)?

Comment: Yes I am sorry. I think I figured out the transition matrix: $P=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1/6  & 1/6 &1/6 &1/6 &1/6 &1/6 & 0 \\
 1/4 & 0 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 &1/4\\
 1/4 & 1/4  & 0 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1/4\\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}  & 0 & \frac{1}{4}  & 0 &0 & \frac{1}{4}\\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}\\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0& 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}\\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4}  & 0 & \frac{1}{4}\\
  0 & 1/6 &1/6 &1/6 &1/6&1/6 &1/6& 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
Now I need to find $\gamma_i^k$

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the Markov chain transition matrix entry $a_{ij}$ you need to know the probability that you visit vertex $j$ when starting from $i$.

If that probability is uniform on edges at each vertex then it's $1/6$ for $6$ of the $8$ vertices when you are leaving the top, since you don't stay where you are and can't go to the bottom.

You should be able to figure out the rest.